# Code to pull webpage data from Internet fails on android despite working correctly when isolated

Tags: java, android, json, urlconnection

I have java code that works fine when used on it's own but fails when incorporated into an android application. It's purpose is to pull JSON from the url. (Please note, the url in use is a test url, and so appears to be missing input data. This is not the issue).

```
public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            try 
            {
                final URL url = new URL("https://apps.bilis.ph/ar/?p={}&lat={}&lon={}&i={}&p={}");
                final URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                urlConnection.connect();
                final InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while (inputStream.available() > 0) 
                {
                    sb.append((char) inputStream.read());
                }
                String result = sb.toString();
                System.out.println(result);

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                //CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast hgtoast = Toast.makeText(context, result, duration);
                hgtoast.show();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.print(e);

                String notwerk = "Internet connection failure";
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                //CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast failtoast = Toast.makeText(context, notwerk, duration);
                failtoast.show();
            }

        }
```

Android permissions to allow internet connection have been used. When the button is clicked the error toast within the code is shown. Again, the code (without toasts) runs completely fine when in an isolated class. Eclipse has detected no errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you observe the exception you can find that  [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) is thrown. Because from api level 11 you can not perform Network operations within main UI thread. Use an [AsyncTask](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html&ei=jtSpUZfjG8GArgef-YD4BQ&usg=AFQjCNE8gLVXz1Hwq4rI8oxRkZNHjhRzpQ&sig2=Fd1cHdCCQ1wxJ_2NcP3GsA&bvm=bv.47244034,d.bmk) instead to perform network operations